# Excel VBA - Object Does not Support this property or method

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

i am trying to get data from a page but i am getting error "Object does not support this property or method" when i am trying to get title

source of page is

```
<div class="title">
<span title="Naviforce Men's Black Dial Leather Band Watch - NF9055-BKRD">Naviforce Men's Black Dial Leather Band Watch - NF9055-BKRD</span>
</div>
```

my vba code is

```
title = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClass("title").innerText)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = title
```

and i have added two refrences "microsoft HTML object library" and "Microsoft internet controls"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function is `getElementsByClass`, it means you get "elements" (plurial). Your error is that "innerText" does not exist in this list container.

You Have to take the first element of the list to retrieve your DOM Element

```
title = Trim(Doc.getElementsByClass("title")(1).innerText)
```

Comment: yes in my source code there are many Class="title" tags, i tried your code with ("title")(0) for first tag, but still its not working, now its giving me blank cell.

Comment: if there are many Class="title", is the first occurrence is empty? if so it's normal you retrieve a blank cell. You have to iterate through the list until you find the one you want

Comment: no, first occurenece is my title and it is not empty, i think there is some problem with refrence of vba.

Comment: The first entry is empty based on the html posted. Try iterating over the collection to find what you are looking for.